# Reading the Microsoft Exchange Email in C#

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

I am getting the exception "The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.".

The version number of Microsoft Exchange is showing up as 14.3.266.4001,Hence am using ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2.Is it the correct Exchange Version?

```
        ExchangeService exchange = null;  
        exchange = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);  
        exchange.Credentials = new WebCredentials("deepak.kothari", "*****", "domain.com");

        exchange.AutodiscoverUrl("deepak.kothari@domain.com");

        Console.WriteLine("Connected to Exchange Server : " + exchange.Url.Host);
```

Please help me resolve the above exception.

Note : I am working virtual machine. And I am trying to access the Microsoft Exchange which is residing in another machine.

Let me know if I can use any other library which is freely available for the above purpose in case?

Comment: Are you sure the AutoDiscover services are set up on your Exchange server?  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb201695(v=exchg.141).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the information! If configuring  Set- WebServicesVirtualDirectory enough? or we need to configure others too...?

Comment: The docs say that `.AutodiscoverUrl()` will try all of the possible paths. So, I would start with just configuring one of them.

Answer (score 0):

First go to this page https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/

1. select "Service Account Access (Developers)" + "Next"
2. fill all the data requested
3. press "Run Test"
4. Reviw the "Test Details" page
5. Click "Expand All"
6. Look for this TAG in page "EwsUrl"
7. copy the URL that contains "EWS", example (https://oa-am.msg.xxxxxxxx.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx) yours can be different

I'm usign this code

```
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

string EmailAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailAddress"];
 string DomainUser= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SIGNUM"];
 string DomainPass= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SIGNUMPassword"];
 string NetworkDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NetworkDomain"];

 ExchangeService exchange = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
 exchange.Credentials = new WebCredentials(DomainUser, DomainPass, NetworkDomain);
exchange.Url = new Uri("https://oa-am.msg.xxxxxxx.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
```

After this you can look for emails, folders, download attachments, etc, all you want todo with you exchange server

Comment: Thanks for the respone!! I have run the connectivity test but am unable to find the TAG  "EwsUrl"...in the results.Also Connectivity Test Failed.

Comment: Btw, you can find your autodiscover URL in this test, Why don't try using your code and this autodiscover URL?